# Who should be responsible for closing a stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm writing an application that creates a "Catalog" of files, which can be attributed with other meta data files such as attachments and thumbnails.

I'm trying to abstract the interface to a catalog to the point where a consumer of a catalog does not need to know about the underlying file system used to store the files. So I've created an interface called `IFileSystemAdaptor` which is shown below.

```
public interface IFileSystemAdaptor:IDisposable
{
    void WriteFileData(string fileName, Stream data);
    Stream ReadFileData(string filename);
    void DeleteFileData(string filename);
    void ClearAllData();
    void WriteMetaFileData(string filename, string path, Stream data);
    Stream ReadMetaFileData(string filename, string path);
    void DeleteMetaFileData(string filename, string path);
    void ClearMetaFilesData(string filename);
}
```

Essentially my IFileSystemAdaptor interface exposes a flat list of files, that can also be associated with additional meta data files.

As you can see I'm using references to generic `Stream` objects to abstract the interface to a file's data. This way one implementation of a Catalog could return files from a hard disk, while another could return the data from a web server.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to keep my program from leaving streams open. Is there a rule of thumb for what members should close streams? Should the consumer of a stream close it, or should the member that original created the stream be responsible for closing it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My Rules:

> Should the consumer of a stream close it

1. If I return a stream from a method, the consumer is responsible.  I'm giving it to you, It's your responsilibity.
2. If I accept a stream as a parameter in a method, I don't close it.  When exiting the method, I don't know if the calling method still needs it.  It's your stream, I'm just borrowing it, and I don't want to mess you up.
3. If I create a stream and pass it to another method, my method closes it (or tries to) when I am done with it.  I don't know what you are going to do with it, but it's my stream, so I am responsible for it.

Comment: Generally a good set of rules, though I'd add a fourth: when accepting a stream (or other `IDisposable`) in a constructor or factory method, if the constructed object may outlive anyone else who actually knows about the encapsulated stream/object, one should provide an *option* to have the constructed object's `Dispose` method also dispose the encapsulated stream/object.

Answer (score 2):

My spontaneous thought in this case is that the consumer should hold the responsibility for closing the streams. An `IFileSystemAdaptor` can't know when the consumer is done using the stream, so it also can't decide when to close it.

Answer (score 1):

In effect the last object to use the stream should be responsible for closing it, and that is generally the caller.

Enjoy!