# How to dispose Command

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am reading data from a database (sqlite, Visual Studio 2008, .net 3.5)

I have a scenario, where a datareader is created in a databasedependant layer, and returned to a layer, that is independant from databasse.

```
    internal static SQLiteDataReader GetReader( SQLiteCommand command)
    {
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        command.Dispose();  // Dispose comamnd here? Or is it Ok, not to dispose
                            // command?
        return reader;
    }
```

Or do I have to somehow return the command to the procedure, that consumes the reader and dispose it there. Or is it ok, not to dispose the command?

**Added for explanation**

The question is, if it is ok to dispose the command after the reader is created, but before the data is read from the reader. Or if it would be very harmfull to let the command be disposed by the Garbage Collector, instead calling dispose in code? I also added my suggestion, where to close the command.

I Try to reword the question again, or give an additional explanation:
As demonstrated in the code snippet, the command is disposed before the reader is iterated and closed. This would be a nice solution, because in the code, where the reader is iterated, there is no access to the command. Is the command still needed by the reader, after the reader is created, or can I dispose it right after creation of the rader.

Comment: Disposing an object in code that did not create it is almost always wrong, it causes too many accidents.  This needs to be done in whatever code calls this method.  With high odds that a simple *using* statement gets the job done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739064/who-should-be-responsible-for-closing-a-stream/3739098#3739098

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the reader back like that, you transfer the responsibility to dispose it to the calling code. You would wrap that code in a `using` block:

```
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand( ... )) {
  using (SQLiteDataReader reader = GetReader(command)) {
    // use the reader
  }
}
```

Note that the calling code that passes the command object into the `GetReader` still has the responsibility for it.

Consider if you can rewrite the code in a manner where you don't pass disposable objects between methods so much, that will make the responsibilities easier to follow.

You could for example pass in a delegate that handles reading an item from the data reader, and return a list of items from the function:

```
internal static List<T> GetReader<T>(SQLiteCommand command, Func<SQLiteDataReader, T> readItem) {
  List<T> list = new List<T>();
  using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      list.Add(readItem(reader));
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```